# Howto: WCF service external to solution (not domain!) with AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, frameworks

I've coded a WCF service that is external to the solution I wish to use it in.  I'm doing this so that I can have one service that's reusable across many solutions.  We've already duplicated this service many times as an asmx integral to the solution and it's not a good maintenance scenario.  I'm finally able to have time to tackle gettign this working the right way.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!  All the posts I've seen about this take me in circles.  My solution (and the service) is in VS2010, Framework 4.0, vb.net.

When using the webHttpBinding binding in the endpoint, when I add the service to my solution the reference is getting added, but web.config does not get added with the system.serviceModel configuration group that is needed.  All the articles I can find talk about making the service part of the solution but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas?  Here is the system.serviceModel section of my service's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<services>
  <service name="Com.mydomain.Services.WCF_ACE.ACE">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="Com.mydomain.Services.WCF_ACE.I_ACE" />
          </service>
</services>
```

Comment: what AutoCompleteExtender has to do with your wcf service problem?

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to use a wcf service you built.  It looks like clients section is missing in the attached config file.

And client configuration is always going to be different from service config.  And you can add that manually to the client solution.

Comment: From what I've seen the client config is added to web.config in the solution using the service when the service reference is added.  This isn't happening and I haven't been able to find good documentation for how to define it manually.  I'd prefer to have VS do what it's supposed to do.  All the posts I've seen on using this with AutoCompleteExtender talk about a local asmx or a local ajax-enabled service as part of the solution.  I want the service to be external to the solution.